# Is it possible to display complex HTML content inside TextView?

Tags: android, android-widget, textview

Is it possible to display complex HTML content inside TextView ? My HTML is going to have images and video tags. Is that possible or to use WebView component or there is some simpoler solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use **HTML tags for TextViews, you have to use android.text.Html class, fromHtml()**..

From **Mark Murphy's** Technical Stuff...

**HTML Tags Supported By TextView**

More importantly, it means that you cannot rely on what it will support from release to release.

```
* <a href="...">
* <b>
* <big>
* <blockquote>
* <br>
* <cite>
* <dfn>
* <div align="...">
* <em>
* <font size="..." color="..." face="...">
* <h1>
* <h2>
* <h3>
* <h4>
* <h5>
* <h6>
* <i>
* <img src="...">
* <p>
* <small>
* <strike>
* <strong>
* <sub>
* <sup>
* <tt>
* <u>
```

For more complex HTML tags you have to use **WebView**...

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use `WebView` for complex `HTML` content, use `HTML` content in `TextView` only to give your text view a custom style

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely use WebView instead of TextView. WebView is made for this exact task, so I cannot see why you would want to use TextView in the first place :)